# How to get the latest version of documents in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have versioned documents stored in a MongoDb collection as follows:

```js
    { _id: 'doc1-1', id: doc1, version: 1 ...},
    { _id: 'doc1-2', id: doc1, version: 2 ...},
    { _id: 'doc2-1', id: doc2, version: 1 ...}
```

I want to return all of the latest documents.
Example:

```js
    { _id: 'doc1-2', id: doc1, version: 2 ...},
    { _id: 'doc2-1', id: doc2, version: 1 ...}
```

I know MongoDb includes operators such as Max and First but these do not seem to apply to subsets of documents within a query so I cannot get each document with a Max version of a unique id.

My goal is to return the full document and not project each field if possible. I'm currently using the MongoDb NPM package so that format of solution is preferred but any MongoDb solution is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am using AWS DocumentDb which uses MongoDb 4.0 so some newer Mongo features are not supported.

Comment: Group by id and get max version. See $group.

Answer (score 0):

After some research the only solution I could identify was to  make two separate calls to MongoDB.

First I used an aggregate call and grouped on id and max version.

```js
const results = await collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: { version : -1 }
  },
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: { 
        id: "$id"
      },
      version: { $max: "$version"}
    }
  }
]);
```

This returned the following response with the id and latest version.

```js
{
  _id: { id: "doc1" },
  version: 2
},
{
  _id: { id: "doc2" },
  version: 1
}
```

I then mapped this response to get an array of the id appended with version to use as my query for getting each document.

```js
const _ids = results.map(({ _id: { id }, version }) => (`${id}-${version}`));
const documents = await collection.find({
  _id: { $in: _ids }
});
```

This returned all of the latest versions with the full document and was much more performant than filtering on server. However, I was not able to determine a method to get the complete document in one call so that solution would still be appreciated if possible.

Answer (score 0):

An aggregation like this should work:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$sort: {id: 1, version: -1}},
    {$group: {_id: '$id', doc: {$first: '$$ROOT'}},
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$doc'}}
])
```

First bring your documents into a defined order with the latest version first, then group by id, keeping the first document via [the `$$ROOT` variable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-variables), then unpack that again to retain only the wanted document.

Comment: I'm unfortunately using DocumentDb which uses a subset of MongoDb features as of 4.0 which does not include $$Root apparently. Appreciate the solution though!

Comment: Worst case, a map-reduce can do it as well. Don’t know whether DocumentDb support that though.